# Как убрать рамки у вкладок pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, border

Сделал в Qt Designer окно с четырьмя вкладками, и вот как оно выглядело в самом Qt Designer[image]
Однако после форматирования .ui файла в .py возле иконок появились рамки(код после форматирования я не менял) и я хотел бы убрать эти рамки, но не знаю как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(845, 535)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 845, 535))
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.tabWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab:unselected\n"
"\n"
"{\n"
"background: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"selection-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    \n"
"    selection-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
        self.tabWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(35, 40))
        self.tabWidget.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideNone)
        self.tabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(False)
        self.tabWidget.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setMovable(False)
        self.tabWidget.setTabBarAutoHide(False)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("говнодом.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, icon, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("заметка1.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, icon1, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("СОЛНЫШКО БЛЯТЬ.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, icon2, "")
        self.tab_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_6.setObjectName("tab_6")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("papa.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_6, icon3, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить строку `app.setStyle("fusion")` после строки `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)` и расскажите что у вас получилось.

Comment: @S.Nick, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Попробуйте запустить ваш код где-то в другом месте, я вашей проблемы у себя не наблюдаю.

Comment: проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297730/%d0%9b%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-qt-designer-%d0%b8-python-3-pyqt5/1298302#1298302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ваша проблемма заключается в том, что питон не имеет тех же возможностей для описания обьекта, что UI. Cамый простой способ убрать подобные баги, в QT дизайнере кидать обьекты на окно не как попало, а с использвоанием лойаутов. Это не сложно но значительно уменьшит кол-во проблемм с переходом.

Comment: sorry, о каких багах вы говорите? и каких возможностей не имеет питон для описания объекта?

Comment: о багах компиляции в питон. Пример такого бага есть в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Triangular)
```

Эта строка задает стиль `QTabWidget`.
Если ее убрать будут стандартные вкладки и через .qss придать нужный вид.