# Как изменить QTabWidget в программе?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtabwidget

Как изменить `QTabWidget` в *Pyqt5*, чтобы он выглядел примерно как на скриншоте.

Возможно ли это сделать не создавая отдельные окна? И возможно ли это сделать в приложение *Qt Designer* или обязательно нужен код?

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Я уже отвечал на похожий вопрос
[Левое меню с использованием Qt Designer и Python 3 (PyQt5)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297730) ,
но для вас предложу еще и другой вариант,
который мне больше нравится.

```
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QListWidget, QStackedWidget, 
    QHBoxLayout, QListWidgetItem, QLabel)


class LeftTabWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeftTabWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(800, 600)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self, spacing=0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # List on the left
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        # Cascading window on the right
        self.stackedWidget = QStackedWidget(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(
            self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)
        # Remove the border
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QListWidget.NoFrame)
        # Hide scroll bar
        self.listWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.listWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
        for i in range(5):
            item = QListWidgetItem(
                QIcon('Ok.png'), str('Option %s' % i), self.listWidget)
            item.setSizeHint(QSize(16777215, 60))
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        for i in range(5):
            label = QLabel('This is the page %d' % i, self)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
                randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label)


Stylesheet = """
QListWidget, QListView, QTreeWidget, QTreeView {
    outline: 0px;
}
QListWidget {
    min-width: 120px;
    max-width: 120px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}
QListWidget::item:selected {
    background: rgb(52, 52, 52);
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(9, 187, 7);
}
HistoryPanel::item:hover {background: rgb(52, 52, 52);}
QStackedWidget {background: rgb(30, 30, 30);}
QLabel {color: white;}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    w = LeftTabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]