Как создать боковое меню выбора страницы в PyQt6 или Qt Designer?
Мне нужно создать боковую панель, на которой будут находится кнопки для перехода на нужный лист. В Qt Designer есть нужный виджет Tab Widget, но его нужно как то развернуть, как сделать это? Или как создать такое меню кодом?
Пояснение к функционалу виджета:
Помимо кнопок для переключения, у него как и на скриншоте желательно наличие стрелочек для лучшей навигации. А также scroll на случай если кнопок будет слишком много. А также отслеживание сколько элементов было задействовано на данный момент.

(Сам виджет)
(Виджет в программе)

dynamic.aerospace.inc, похожие вопросы уже задавались, проработайте их https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342102/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-qtabwidget-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8/1342198#1342198 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297730/%d0%9b%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-qt-designer-%d0%b8-pyqt5

@S.Nick посмотрю, но сработает ли такой код на PyQt6?

@S.Nick и в тех вопросах немного не то, виджет выглядит не как отдельные кнопки, а как закладки, а хотелось бы по возможности видеть нечто похожее на скриншот. Возможно ли такое?
